# how to put a rectangle into a fixed width&height area which is already owning some rects

Tags: javascript, typescript, algorithm

As the title says, I'm trying to place some widgets on the screen. It performs well when there are only several widgets in the area, but when the count of widgets comes to 15 or more, it would take more than 5 secs to find a valid position.
Here is the code I already have:

```
export const MAP_ELEMENT_KEYS = new WeakMap<HTMLElement, symbol>()
export const MAP_RECT: { [key: symbol]: DOMRect } = {}
const KEYS: symbol[] = []

const areaWidth = window.innerWidth
const areaHeight = window.innerHeight
const gap = 5

export const getAllRects = (exclude?: HTMLElement): DOMRect[] => {
  return (exclude ? KEYS.filter((key) => key !== (exclude as any).__grid_key) : KEYS).map(
    (key) => MAP_RECT[key]
  )
}

export interface Rect {
  x: number
  y: number
  width: number
  height: number
}

function doesOverlap(rect1: Rect, rect2: Rect) {
  // Returns true if the rectangles overlap, false otherwise. Accounts for the gap.
  return (
    rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width + gap &&
    rect1.x + rect1.width + gap > rect2.x &&
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height + gap &&
    rect1.y + rect1.height + gap > rect2.y
  )
}

function isSpaceFree(x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number) {
  // Proposed rectangle
  const newRect = { x, y, width, height }

  const rects: DOMRect[] = getAllRects()
  // Test for overlap with existing rectangles
  for (const rect of rects) {
    if (doesOverlap(newRect, rect)) {
      return false // Space is not free
    }
  }
  return true // Space is free
}

export function getPosition(width: number, height: number) {
  // Loop through each potential starting position for the new rectangle
  for (let x = areaWidth - width - gap; x > gap; x -= gap) {
    for (let y = gap; y <= areaHeight - height - gap; y += gap) {
      // Check if the space is free using the isSpaceFree function
      if (isSpaceFree(x, y, width, height)) {
        // If space is free, mark it as occupied and return the position
        return { x, y }
      }
    }
  }
  // If no position is found, return null or an indication that the positioning failed
  return null
}
```

[image]

How can I improve the code to get better performance?

Answer (score -4):

To place a rectangle within a fixed width and height area that already contains some rectangles, you can follow these general steps:

Define the Fixed Width and Height:
Determine the fixed width and height of the area where you want to place the rectangle.

Calculate Available Space:
Subtract the total area occupied by existing rectangles from the fixed width and height to find the available space.

Decide on Rectangle Size:
Decide on the size of the rectangle you want to add. Ensure that it fits within the available space.

Choose Placement Strategy:
Determine where you want to place the new rectangle within the available space. You might want to place it in a specific position or follow a specific arrangement strategy.

Adjust for Padding and Margins:
If your rectangles have padding or margins, consider adjusting the available space accordingly to ensure proper placement.

Implement the Placement Logic:
Write code to implement the placement logic based on the decisions you made in steps 3 and 4. This might involve calculating coordinates or using a layout algorithm.

Here's a simple example in Python using a hypothetical scenario. Let's say you have a fixed area of 100x100 and existing rectangles:

```
fixed_width = 100
fixed_height = 100

existing_rectangles = [(10, 10, 30, 30), (50, 20, 80, 40)]  # (x1, y1, x2, y2)

# Calculate available space
available_width = fixed_width - sum(rectangle[2] - rectangle[0] for rectangle in existing_rectangles)
available_height = fixed_height - sum(rectangle[3] - rectangle[1] for rectangle in existing_rectangles)

# Decide on the size of the new rectangle
new_rectangle_width = 20
new_rectangle_height = 20

# Decide on placement strategy (e.g., placing it in the top-left corner)
new_rectangle_x = 0
new_rectangle_y = 0

# Adjust for padding or margins if needed

# Implement the placement logic
if new_rectangle_x + new_rectangle_width <= available_width and new_rectangle_y + new_rectangle_height <= available_height:
    print("Rectangle ca`enter code here`n be placed.")
    # Add code to draw or store the new rectangle's coordinates
else:
    print("Not enough space for the new rectangle.")
```

Comment: [ChatGPT is banned at SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) Also you could not even ask it to do a JavaScript answer when OP tagged JS?